# A bug in this code i can't resolve. Run time SIGSEGV

Tags: c, runtime-error, segmentation-fault

I was trying this problem on codechef
the output is coming right as far as i have checked.
but when i am submitting it on codechef a `runtime error` is coming (SIGSEGV).

Please help me to find the solution to the problem

[This is the link to the error](http://tinypic.com/r/2jdp3s6/8)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int m=0;
    long int i=0,j=0 ,c=0,t=0,v=0,a=0 ;
    long int n=0,q=0,x[10]={0},y[10]={0},s[10]={0},f[10]={0};
    long int p[10][10]={0},cl[10]={0};

   /*arrays--
    x and y for coordinates
   s and f for start and finish of the trips
   p is 2-d array for differences
   cl for storing minimums
   */   
//printf("Enter the number of test cases");
scanf("%d",&t);
for(m =0;m <t;m++)//test cases
{
    //printf("Enter the number of chambers\n");

    scanf("%ld",&n);//number of chambers

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)//co-ordinates
        scanf("%ld%ld",&x[i],&y[i]);

    //printf("Enter the number of trips q\n");
    scanf("%ld",&q);//no. of trips

    for(i=0;i<q;i++)//the trips
        scanf("%ld%ld",&s[i],&f[i]);

    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)//loop for calculating the difference between the co ordinates
        for(j=i;j<n-1;j++)
            p[i][j]=abs(x[i]-x[j+1])+abs(y[i]-y[j+1]);

    /*for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
            printf("%d\t",p[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
     }*/

    for(v=0;v<q;v++) //loop for the no. of times the trips
    {
        a=0;
        for(i=s[v]-1;i<f[v]-1;i++)
        {
            cl[a]=p[i][i];
            for(j=i;j<f[v]-1;j++)
            {
                if(p[i][j]<cl[a])
                    cl[a]=p[i][j];
            }
            a++;                
        }
        /*for(i=0;i<a;i++)
            printf("%d\n",cl[i]);*/
        c=cl[0];
        for(i=0;i<a;i++)
        {
            if(cl[i]>c)
                c=cl[i];
            cl[i]=0;
        }               
        printf("%ld\n",c);
    }
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: what are your runtime inputs

Comment: @ArjunSreedharan a bug should not depend on runtime inputs. Code must be robust enough to handle any input.

Comment: I see a bug in your code, that might or not cause problems, you ignore the return value of `scanf()` which might lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: accessing array indexes here are predicated on the input `n`. Could be accessing out of bound memory

Comment: So a check on their values would prevent that, and there would be no bug, and this `for(i=s[v]-1;i<f[v]-1;i++)` looks like the problem which would be related to your comment @ArjunSreedharan

Comment: Check compiler warnings: there is one wrong initialization and wrong usage of variables in `scanf()`.

Comment: What is your `sizeof(long int)`? You are using the `%d` specifier in `scanf("%d",&t);`

Comment: I did run the same code on IDE on my laptop and also on codechef/ide...and i encountered no error..and the output came out perfectly fine..
this problem is coming only on submitting the answer on codechef

Comment: @weather_vane i rectified the problem you pointed out and still the same problem is coming